# Anyone know how can I turn my Mac terminal into this?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

How can I make my Mac terminal look like the screenshot below? The input line is cool and seems useful.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You mean the prompt line? That is done by setting the PS1 environment variable in the .bashrc file (or .bash_profile) in your home directory.

See: http://beckism.com/2009/02/better_bash_prompt/

Comment: lynda.com has a decent lesson on configuring BASH profiles in their Mac UNIX video tutorial. it's not free, but the OP might find it interesting

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the guy in the picture you sent uses Rails and GIT. 
If you are using git, you should download [GIT Bash Completition](http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2008/02/git_bash_comple.html) to and
change your .bash_profile, including this 2 lines:

```
source ~/.git-completion.bash
export PS1='\[\033[38m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \[\033[31m\]`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep \* | head -1 |  sed "s/\* //g" | awk "{ print \"(\" \\\$1 \")\" }"`\[\033[29m\]$\[\033[00m\] '
```

With this you will have a nice prompt, which tells you what branch you are.

Comment: Actually the Git completion file provides a ready-made item to export into PS1. They suggest this, for example, `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '`

Answer (score 0):

You can have this UI and a lot more functionalities if you install ITerm(https://www.iterm2.com). It is a terminal emulator for MAX OS and has some advanced features.